# How to run music and a game using multithreading in C?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to run music in my raycaster-type game which uses the X Windows protocol. I've read a few tutorials about multithreading but I'm not sure I get it.

I created  and exectued my two threads, as such :

```
pthread_create(&song, NULL, ft_sound, NULL);
pthread_create(&dance, NULL, ft_go, &mega);
pthread_join(dance, NULL);
pthread_join(song, NULL);
```

In which `ft_sound` is my function running the music and `ft_go` the function running the raycaster, `mega` being the structure storing all I need for it.

Here are the functions in question :

```
static void *ft_sound(void *vargp)
{
    (void)(vargp);
    sleep(10);
    execlp("aplay", "aplay", "-q", "./music.wav", NULL);
    return (NULL);
}
```

```
static void *ft_go(void *vargp)
{
    t_mega  *mega;

    mega = vargp;

    mega->win = mlx_new_window(mega->mlxp, mega->map.res[0], mega->map.res[1], "CUB3D");
    ft_raycast(mega, &mega->eng, &mega->map, -1);
    mlx_hook(mega->win, 3, 3, ft_key_press, mega);
    mlx_loop(mega->mlxp);
    ft_free_map(&mega->map);
    return (NULL);
}
```

(the mlx functions are custom functions made by my school for this appointment, they handle the key presses for the game.)

But as soon as the song starts, the dance ends, even if I swap the join lines. How do I make both my threads run at the same time ?

Comment: Its extremely hard to guess what's happening by just looking at 4 lines of code, you have to share at least [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Without going into too much detail here, I'd suggest taking another look at the documentation for `pthread_join()`, as it's probably not what you want here.

Comment: @scg That's the whole problem here, I don't know what I want to use. If I knew, I wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: @lrAM You're right. I've added the bodies of the called functions.

Comment: Your sound thread calls `execlp` which is a process global action, you might want to look at that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you replace the body of `ft_sound` with just `printf("sound")` and the body of `ft_go` with just `printf("go")` does that much work correctly?

Comment: @Wyck yes, both functions execute normally, except for the whole sutting down thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execlp("aplay", "aplay", "-q", "./music.wav", NULL);`

replaces the entire executable (not just the current thread) with an instance of `aplay`. So as soon as you call execlp, your raytracing thread vanishes.

If you need to provide a multithreaded solution, you will have to find a library which can play the music without invoking an external utility. Alternatively, you could just fork a separate process which executes aplay. (Mixing threads and forking is possibly, with a bit of care. But there doesn't seem to be any need here.)

Comment: I don't necessarily have to use threads, it's just the way a co-student told me to do it. The same also told me to be careful with forking, but I'll look into it if threads aren't usable.